# Como não permitir digitar mais de 10 caracteres com WYSIWYG?

Tags: javascript, html5

Segue o código:

**Html:**

```
<textarea id="summernote">Escrever aqui</textarea>
<h5 id="limite_vermelho" style="text-align:right;color:red"></h5>
<h5 id="limite_normal" style="text-align:right"></h5>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#summernote').on('summernote.keyup', function(e) {
    debugger;
    var text = $(this).next('.note-editor').find('.note-editable').text();
    var length = text.length;
    var num = 10 - length;

    if (length > 10) {
        $('#limite_normal').hide();
        $('#limite_vermelho').text(10 - length).show();
    }
    else{
        $('#limite_vermelho').hide();
        $('#limite_normal').text(10 - length).show();
    }

});
```

Ou se preferir em jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dtgr5q29/112/

Ele não pode digitar mais de 10 caracteres, como posso fazer isso com jquery ?

Comment: Tenho que dizer que isso não faz muito sentido em um editor WYSIWYG, pois se o usuário, por exemplo, definir um texto em negrito, só as tags HTML ocuparam 7 caracteres (`<b></b>`). Tem certeza que esta é a melhor solução para o problema?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, Mesmo digitando em negrito, ele não conta. Observe na linha: `var text = $(this).next('.note-editor').find('.note-editable').text();`, existe maneira de parar a digitar o teclado quando for maior que  10 ?

Comment: Então, seria apenas substituir o texto por ele mesmo quando o cara fosse digitar, algo como ``$(textarea).text(texto)``, com ``textarea`` apontando pro mesmo lugar de onde você está tirando a variável ``text`` no seu código. O problema é que o WISIWYG deve estar com um evento ``keyup`` junto do seu, então: ou você usa um campo simples, ou vai precisar retirar o evento do WISIWYG e reexecutá-lo. Vou tentar aqui, sei lá...

Comment: Olhei a documentação, acho que é só usar o evento ``onKeyUp`` http://summernote.org/deep-dive/#onkeyup-onkeydown

Comment: @Daniel, parece que eu descobri o problema, por favor verifique: https://jsfiddle.net/dtgr5q29/117/

Comment: Problema ainda não foi corrigido, ao digitar 10 caracteres em negrito, ele perde. Parece @AndersonCarlosWoss tem razão.

Comment: tá aí, funcionando... sempre que a gente usa bibliotecas de outras pessoas, é bom olhar a documentação deles. Algumas são muito muito fodas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O summernote tem várias [funções de callback](http://summernote.org/deep-dive/#callbacks) na documentação dele. Entre elas, a `onKeyup`. Então, basta incluir essa callback na hora de iniciar o objeto:

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
  callbacks: {
  onKeydown: function(e) {
   var textarea = $(this).next('.note-editor').find('.note-editable');
   var texto = $(textarea).text();

   if (texto.length > 10) {
     // apaga o texto que foi digitado
     $('#summernote').summernote('reset');
     // insere o texto dentro do limite desejado (no caso 10)
     $('#summernote').summernote('insertText', texto.substr(0, 10));
   }
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: Bom trabalho Daniel, será que é possivel manter texto em negrito sem resetar ?

Comment: Ihhh... aí não sei. Provavelmente se você conseguir pegar o HTML ao invés do texto e converter pra node, pode usar a ``insertNode`` ao invés de texto.

Comment: Se conseguir resolver, posta aí a solução, beleza?

Comment: Daniel consegui, veja minha resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/239743/54019 funciona com cor da letra tbm.